# Can't select item with jQuery .select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery and Javascript so maybe someone can help me out?
I used .select2 to get this result but I'm not able to select and item.
Here is the code

JAVASCRIPT

```
 $("#namesCombobox").select2({
        placeholder: "Search for a name",
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        ajax: {
            url: "/api/machineparkcustomers/getnamescontaining",
            dataType: 'json',
            quietMillis: 250,
            data: function (term, page) {
                return {
                    query: term,
                };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            cache: true
        },
        formatResult: function (state) {
            return state;
        }



    });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="namesCombobox" class="col-sm-12" />
```

Comment: What is `select2`? Can you share more code and also is there any error in console?

Comment: `url` what you are passing might be wrong.

Comment: just make sure you have the library `select2` as well as jquery properly loaded

Comment: Can you please paste the absolute ajax URL here?

Comment: Is the return from the `results` should be `data.items`? (`return { results: data.items };`

Comment: This is select2 http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: There is not wrong with retrieving the data, but I can't click my results

Comment: `initSelection`, `Called when Select2 is created to allow the user to initialize the selection based on the value of the element select2 is attached to.`. As I see in this page, http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: the InitSelection doesn't to anything with me. I just search names in a database, collect them and show them in a list. Now I just want the name to appear in my search field when I click it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show what the data looks like that your ajax request returns, but judging by your `formatSelection` function and the behavior you are experiencing, I am guessing that the data is an array of strings. What it should be is an array of objects, where each object has an `id` property and a `text` property.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yp39vygb/4/) shows the problem.

Try changing the ajax `results` function to this:

```
results: function(data) {
    return { results: $.map(data, function(state) {
        return { id: state, text: state }
    }) };
}
```

You will also have to remove the `formatResult` function.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yp39vygb/3/)

Comment: the formatResult is correct as far as I see because when I change it I don't get anymore results in my autocomplete box. The real problem is that I can't click my results.

Comment: In that case, the problem is with the data being returned and the `results` function. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found this question while searching for a solution to a similar problem The accepted answer is great, but not my issue.

Select2 provides a callback "id" function that it will invoke to determine the ID you'd like to use for each result in the data. For my case my "id" function was not correct.

```
    this.el.select2({
        minimumInputLength: 12,
        query: this.search.bind(self),
        id: function (clinicianDto) { return clinicianDto.id(); },
        formatResult: function (clinicianDto: any) {                
            return "<div class='row'><div class='col-sm-12' >" + clinicianDto.firstName() + ' ' + clinicianDto.lastName() + "</div></div>";                
        },
        formatSelection: function (clinicianDto: any) {
            return clinicianDto.firstName() + ' ' + clinicianDto.lastName();
        },
        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
            if (self.selectedClinician) {
                callback(self.selectedClinician.SerializeModel());
            }
        }
```